# sed: match the hold space against the pattern space

Tags: recursion, sed, pattern-matching

I'm looking for a `sed` command to match the contents of the hold space against the pattern space. For example, suppose the hypothetical `{h}` token refers to the contents of the hold space:

```
echo "foo: one foo three" | sed -n     \
    -e 'h; s/^\(.*\):.*$/\1/'          \
    -e 'x; s/.*: \(.*\)$/\1/'          \
    -e '/{h}/ p'
```

The first `-e` puts the whole `echo` into the hold space, then reduces the pattern space to just the initial "foo". The second `-e` swaps "foo" into the hold space and reduces the original `echo` to the trailing "one foo three". The third (hypothetical) `-e` attempts to match the hold space "foo" against the pattern space "one foo three". Of course there is no such token `{h}`, but if there were, the pattern space would match, and the output would be:

```
one foo three
```

Does `sed` provide any way to do this?

My goal here is to count all such matches in a large file (4MB). It can alternatively be done with a `while read` loop, but it requires starting at least 3 subprocesses per line, which turns out to be quite slow! Any suggestions are welcome if `sed` just doesn't do this.

Comment: If I understood it right: Do you want to compare if the word before the colon is one of the words after the colon? And if it matches print all characters after the colon, and if it doesn't match skip line, is like that?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Jotne's answer does the trick.

Comment: I asked it because it's easy to do it with `sed` too using backreferences (`\1`) instead of the `hold space`.

Comment: How? I'm getting `Invalid back reference` when I try to make a reference in a match expression to a capture from a previous expression.

Comment: I've added the `sed` command as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not `sed`, but some like this?

```
echo "foo: one foo three" | awk -F": " '$2~$1 {print $2}'
one foo three
```

Answer (score 4):

Here it's the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution:

```
sed -ne '/^\([^:]*\):.*\1/ p' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
foo: one foo three
foo: one loo three
troo: one foo three
three: one foo three
```

It yields:

```
foo: one foo three
three: one foo three
```

Comment: Cool, that works too. I already accepted Jotne's answer, but this is what I was originally going for.

Comment: In case one line would be 'foo: one foobar three' sed -ne '/^\([^:]*\):.*\b\1\b/ p' would be a safer solution. Still, it needs a separator char ':' and does not match hold against pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As has been shown, the "correct" (simplest) approach for this particular task is to do the matching without using the hold space at all.

But, for a fun exercise, what if you really *had* to use the hold space (maybe as part of a much more complex sed program)?

Assuming the hold space does not contain any `\n` (as is the case in the original question above), the following will work:

```
-e 'H;g;s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\1.*\)/\2/p'
```

This will append the pattern space to the hold space (separated by `\n`), then copy it back to the pattern space, and match the first line (i.e. the original hold space) against the rest (i.e. the original pattern space). If a match occurs, the original pattern space is restored by discarding its first line, then the result is printed.

(Note that no requirement was given for the match to occur within word boundaries - or even whether the hold space only has a single word. For example, `foo bar` in the hold space will match `loofoo barzoo` in the pattern space. If that is not desirable, adding `\b` before and after `\1` above should do the trick.)

To extend the fun, let's also require preserving the original hold space for future matches in the same sed program. In order to do that, after the code above, we'll copy the modified hold space to the pattern space again, then discard everything except the first line (i.e. the original hold space), then put it back in the hold space:

```
-e 'g;s/\n.*//;h'
```

Putting it all together for the original question, the complete sed command would be:

```
echo "foo: one foo three" | sed -n            \
    -e 'h; s/^\(.*\):.*$/\1/'                 \
    -e 'x; s/.*: \(.*\)$/\1/'                 \
    -e 'H; g; s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\1.*\)/\2/p' \
    -e 'g; s/\n.*//; h'
```

*(And you can see why, strictly in the scope of the original question, this is not the best approach. Also in the scope of the original question, the last `-e` does not do anything useful and can be omitted.)*